# MKMapView custom pins change when I zoom in and out

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm making an app that uses MKMapView. I add custom pins (with image). And now when I zoom in and then zoom out, pins change back to default (red color).

Here is my code:

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
    {
        static NSString* SFAnnotationIdentifier = @"Kamera";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView =
        (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

            UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinModer.png"];

            CGRect resizeRect;

            resizeRect.size = flagImage.size;
            resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(40, 60);
            resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
            [flagImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            annotationView.image = resizedImage;
            annotationView.opaque = NO;

            UIImageView *sfIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"kameraNaprejModra.png"]];
            annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = sfIconView;

            return annotationView;

    }    
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is not handling the case where the `dequeue` returns a non-nil `pinView` (meaning it is re-using a previous annotation view).

If `pinView` is not `nil`, the method ends up at the last line which returns `nil` for the annotation view.

When you return `nil`, the map view draws the default annotation view which is a red pin.

Adjust the code like this:

```
if (!pinView)
{
    //no changes to code inside this if
    //...
    return annotationView;
}
//add an else part and return pinView instead of nil...
else
{
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
}

return pinView;
```